# Simple Dom PHP find element

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have this piece of html:

```
<div id="items">
   <div class="entry">
```

using simple html dom i want to find `<div class="entry">` and i have the following code:

```
if ($site === 'test') {
    $div = $html->find('div[id=items]',0);
    $list = $div->find('div[class=entry]'); 
    foreach($list as $item) {
        $link = $item->find('h3 a', 0)->href;
        $headline = $item->find('h3 a', 0)->innertext;
        $image = NULL;
        $stories[] = array('link' => $link, 'headline' => $headline, 'image' => $image);
    }
}
```

It seems to be complaining that it cannot find `<div class="entry">`even though i have it here `$list = $div->find('div[class=entry]');`

Any Ideas Anyone?

Comment: Can I ask what library you're using to find DOM elements, and secondly why you chose that style of implementation with PHP? This is more of the kind of thing you would implement in the front-end in most cases, so I'm interested to know why.

Comment: Because you never close your tags?

Answer (score 1):

What about trying to get the div with this:

```
$list = $html->find('div[id=items] div.entry');
```

Comment: There's no `<td class="entry">` in his HTML.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! meant to write 'div' not 'td', it's fixed now